# bash scripting: how do I replace these lines matching a pattern with another line?

Tags: xml, bash, replace, sed

I need to process a set of XML files in a current directory using `sed` or a similar utility from within a `bash` script.

In each file that has either of the following lines (there might be 0 or 1 of them in a file)

```
    <MetaDatum key="Pr" value="VALUE (foobar)" />
    <MetaDatum key="Pr" value="VALUE (xyz12345678)" />
```

I need to replace that entire line with

```
    <MetaDatum key="Pr" value="VALUE" />
```

So what I need to do is essentially map `VALUE (foobar)` and `VALUE (xyz12345678)` into `VALUE`.

So what operation should I use inside this loop:

```
for f in `grep -l "MetaDatum key=\"Pr\" value=\"VALUE" *.xml`
do
     # replace one entire line in $f with '<MetaDatum key="Pr" value="VALUE" />'
done
```

Comment: How much of the rest of that line is unique to the lines you want to edit? Is `<MetaDatum` enough? Do you need `<MetaDatum key="Pr"`? More? Are those quotes always double quotes? Are they always on lines by themselves? If you don't have reliable answers to those questions then you should probably look into using something that is intended to manipulate XML. Like XSLT or xmlstarlet.

Comment: @EtanReisner: `grep -l` returns the files.

Comment: Yes, thanks, forgot the `-l`. The rest of your q's: `<MetaDatum key="Pr"` would be enough. The lines I need to modify are always by themselves. Yes, always `"`

Comment: BTW, for the general case (not XML), this is a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021

Comment: There are situations other than those we've already mentioned where `sed` will do the wrong thing, btw. It doesn't know anything about XML comments; it doesn't know anything about CDATA sections; it doesn't know anything about how to escape values to make them valid inside XML (think about if your value has a `&` in it and needs to be replaced with `&amp;` to generate a valid file). Part of the advantage of using an XML-aware tool is that they'll exit with an error rather than generate an invalid output file, but `sed` will generate files that aren't valid XML all day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the pattern in your `grep` command identifies all the lines that need to be modified and no other lines, you could write a `sed` command that matches the same lines, and substitutes the value of the `value` attribute on it:

```
sed '/MetaDatum key="Pr" value="VALUE/ s/value="[^"]*"/value="VALUE"/' $f
```

Note, however, that that approach (both `grep` and `sed`) is very sensitive to the exact details of your XML.  It will fall over on different amounts of whitespace than you expect -- especially embedded newlines -- on extra attributes, on different choice of quotes, etc..

Some of those can be addressed by smarter patterns, but others not.  To properly process XML, you want bona fide XML tools.  In this case, an appropriate tool would be an XSLT transform.  Here's a transform that would do the job (provided that the source file has not overridden the default XML namespace -- thanks, CharlesDuffy):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity transform: anything not otherwise matched is copied verbatim -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
    -- Transform the 'value' attribute of MetaDatum elements where the
    -- element has a 'key' attribute with value 'Pr', and the 'value'
    -- attribute's own value starts with 'VALUE'.
    -->
  <xsl:template match="MetaDatum[@key = 'Pr']/@value[substring(., 1, 5) = 'VALUE']">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">VALUE</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could apply it via any XSLT processor, but one of the more common of those is `xsltproc`, which comes with GNOME's libxslt.  If the transform stored in file `meta.xsl`, then the commands to replace a file `$f` with the transformed output via `xsltproc` might be:

```
temp=`mktemp` && xsltproc meta.xsl "$f" > "$temp" && mv "$temp" "$f"
```

As @CharlesDuffy observed in comments, that may result in the file named by `$f` having different ownership and/or more restrictive permissions than it did before.  How you might resolve that issue depends on the available tools.  For example, although standard `chown` and `chmod` don't have it, the GNU versions have mechanisms for setting ownership and permissions of a file to match those of a different file.  Additionally, you'll want to consider what the desired behavior is for the case when `$f` names a symbolic link (replace the link, or modify the file to which it points).  Since these are environment- and prefence-dependent matters, if the command presented above does not handle them as you like then you'll need to decide how to revise the approach.

If you need to deal with an overridden default XML namespace, then the template will need to be a bit more complicated.  You'll need to declare a namespace prefix for the namespace of the `MetaDatum` element and its attributes, and to use it wherever you refer to those names.

Comment: Excellent. Only case not covered here is if the OP's actual file has its default namespace overridden.

Comment: One caveat with the one-liner, by the way -- it's potentially making permissions significantly more restrictive (as `mktemp` uses a conservative umask). If this is a GNU system, you could use `chown --reference="$f"`, `chmod --reference="$f"`, etc. to copy ownership and permissions across.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, all good points.  I have revised my answer to discuss them, though I didn't modify the stylesheet or one-liner.  I think it reasonable to let the OP adapt the answer to his specific needs himself, to whatever extent that is required.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `sed`, use a tool that properly parses the XML. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) you can use

```
for $file in { glob '*.xml' } {
    open $file ;
    for //MetaDatum/@value
        set . xsh:subst(., 'VALUE \(.*', 'VALUE') ;
    save :b ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably use `sed` for this job: XML can be written out in too many different ways. (For instance, your document could have the key and value attributes on different lines from the value they apply to, or could put "value" before "key", or could start using named namespaces and thus adding `foo:` prefixes on things). There's no guarantee that future versions of your input file will be generated with the exact same formatting, particularly as the code that generates it changes.

Instead, use an XML-aware tool such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//MetaDatum[@key="Pr"]/@value' \
  -v "VALUE" \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

---

Note that if there's an `xmlns="..."` declaration at an enclosing scope in your file, this will change the expression above a bit. (This also means that your file format is using namespaces, so particularly likely to change in ways sed can't handle!)

For instance, if the top of your file starts with something like `<root xmlns="http://example.com/foo">`, then you'd need to do the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -N "foo=http://example.com/foo"
  -u '//foo:MetaDatum[@key="Pr"]/@value' \
  -v "VALUE" \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

---

By the way -- if you'd rather perform edits in-place, `xmlstarlet ed` has a `-i` option to make changes inline; thus: `xmlstarlet ed -i [...] changeme.xml` will write out a modified version of `changeme.xml`, allowing `find` one-liners shown by some other answers to be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sed one-liner command to modify all the xml files (inside the current directory) in place:

```
sed -i 's,\(<MetaDatum\s*key="Pr"\s*value="VALUE\).*\s*/>,\1" />,' *.xml
```

You can also make a backup copy of the previous version adding something after the `-i` switch, such as a `.bak` suffix (or `~` if:

```
sed -i.bak 's,\(<MetaDatum\s*key="Pr"\s*value="VALUE\).*\s*/>,\1" />,' *.xml
```

Combine the command with `find` tool to apply sed to files with an .xml extension (case insensitive) that can be found in target directory or its subdirectories:

```
find ${targetDir} -type f -iname "*.xml" -exec sed -i 's,\(<MetaDatum\s*key="Pr"\s*value="VALUE\).*\s*/>,\1" />,' {} \;
```